# How do I check the runtime/status of a python script in bash?

Tags: python, bash, unix, runtime, status

I have a python script `script.py`. I decide to execute this in the Terminal.

```
python script.py
```

It has been running for several hours. How do I check the status? How can I check whether this program is still responsive?

`top` doesn't work in this case, as the program is still running. I think there's a keyboard command---i't's something like 'Control' + 'something'

Comment: can't you print from your script itself, that what it is currently doing!

Comment: Well what's it doing? Could you add `logging`?

Comment: @praba230890 There is a keyboard command which allows you to see for how long the process has been running. This is the preferred option.

Comment: @jonrsharpe Running the script. That Terminal window is inaccessible as long as the script hasn't completed.

Comment: No, I mean *what is the script doing?*

Comment: @ShanZhengYang You can suspend a process with `<C-z>` than continue it as a background process with `bg`.

Comment: @jonrsharpe Nothing special. I'm manipulating about 15 GB of data frames and outputting to other files. For this command, it doesn't matter what the script is doing, I believe.

Comment: @andlrc After suspending/stopping the script, how do I "un-suspend it"? Doesn't `bg` restart the program?

Comment: Well then how many of the files you expected in output have turned up? That would give you some idea of the progress, surely?

Comment: @ShanZhengYang The process is not stopped just suspended. Typing `jobs` will give info about processes connected to your shell. You can bring a suspended process to the background with `bg` and foreground with `fg`.

Comment: You can monitor the process system calls with `strace`. Get its PID and then do `sudo strace -p <thepid>` (and optionally add `-o tracefile.txt` to send the trace to a file). This may dump a lot of data to just run it for a short "peek" at what's going on.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

While your program is still running type `C-z` (while pressing 'Ctrl' press 'z')
You wille get a output like this:

```
[1]  + 2267 suspended  

python script.py
```

Then you can get the current runtime with:

```
ps -p "2267" -o etime
```

Replace "2267" with the pid shown in step 1.
When you want to resume your script type:

```
fg %1
```

You can think of `%1` as the current count of "backgrounded" processes. If the output after `C-z` shows something e.g. `[4] + XXXX suspended` means that you must use `fg %4` to resume the process.

Comment: When using this command to output the ELAPSED runtime: 

    ps -p "PID_NUMBER" -o etime

Is it possible to program this command to output a time every 5-10 minutes? That is, without user input?

Comment: @ShanZhengYang `while ps -p pid -o etime; do sleep 300; done`